# Why the container goes up when a child element font size is increased?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements next to each other, The content and everything is the same, But when I set a big font size to one of them, That one goes up.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8eLps3f2/13

As you see when I gave the `a` inside the first element `font-size: 300%` which means that the text will exceed the width, The first element goes up.

Shouldn't it goes down to fit the content?

Is that's normal?

If not, How to fix it so that the container goes down with the content, Not going up.

Here is the code:

```
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin: 5% auto
}

.child{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}

.first{
  background-color: #444
}

.second{
  background-color: #eee
}

.third{
  background-color: #aaa
}

.first a{
  font-size:200%
 }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child first">
    <div>first</div>
    <h3>This is the 1st child</h3>
    <a>This is link for 1st child</a>
  </div> <!-- .first -->
  <div class="child second">
    <div>second</div>
    <h3>This is the 2nd child</h3>
    <a>This is link for 2nd child</a>
  </div> <!-- .second -->
  <div class="child third">
    <div>third</div>
    <h3>This is the 3rd child</h3>
    <a>This is link for 3rd child</a>
  </div> <!-- .third -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not set a `vertical-align` property, and its default value is `baseline`.

Add the `vertical-align: baseline|length|sub|super|top|text-top|middle|bottom|text-bottom|initial|inherit;` to your `.child`

```
.child {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp